# Update daterangepicker with an event

Tags: angular, calendar, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using this calendar on my angular2 app:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-daterangepicker

http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options

I am facing the problem of updating the settings when some event occures.

How could I do that? It seems like there is no way of updating the settings once they are initialized.

I want to update the locale object that is related to language (when user translate website from english to another language, I need to pass different locale values).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can update the settings the same way you initially set them, by calling `$.daterangepicker(settings)` again.

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported from version 2.0.8